# Highlight input text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello I would like the text inside an input element to highlight upon initial click. However my function does not seem to be working. I have researched the issue and seen that there are some issues with jquery 1.7 and below. I have adjusted it to account for this any it still does not work.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

HTML

```
 <input type="text" value="hello"/>
```

JS

```
  $scope.highlightText = function() {
    $("input[type='text']").on("click", function() {
      $(this).select();
    });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/b7TYAFQNkhjE6lpRSWTR?p=preview

Comment: What Is Your Question?

Comment: How do I get the text inside the input element to highlight when I click inside it

Comment: You can make use of   ng-click="highlightText()"

Comment: That sounds ideal. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call your method at the end of controller, otherwise the event is not bound.

https://plnkr.co/edit/a0BlekB8qTGOmWS8asIx?p=preview

... other code ...

```
        $scope.highlightText = function () {
                    $("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {
                        $(this).select();
                        var test = $(this).parent();
                        console.log(test);
                    });

        $("textarea").on("click", function () {
                        $(this).select();
            });
        };
    $scope.highlightText();
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the text inside an input you would simply call `this.select()` from `onclick` like shown below

```html
<input type="text" onclick="this.select()" value="hello"/>
```

Comment: Thats an awesome solution. Thanks!